# Hibernate: maintaining previous versions of entities

Tags: java, hibernate, history

Is there a standard way of maintaining a history of Entity versions using hibernate?

Or is it a case of getting the database to add records to an archive table on update/delete and having a separate archive entity?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the most "standard" way would be using "Envers", see "http://www.jboss.org/envers".